# Pandas Time Series from text

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

Python has time series libraries within Pandas. I have a text file in python program that is a simple counter for most frequent words and days.Can I use Pandas library to make simple time line for most frequent words?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Not knowing the exact structure of your data, hard to give you exact code, but once you learn the library it should not be very difficult. Check out [my upcoming book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do) (/shameless self promotion) or the pandas documentation for good learning resources.